# Issue with enabling html5 mode in angular js to remove # from URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, tomcat7, angular-ui-router

I searched a lot in stackoverflow and web regarding this and no where I got a straight answer to my question.  Hence requesting for help.  Here is my problem:

I enabled 'html5mode' in my angular js application to remove the '#' symbol from the URL.  After enabling I am successfully able to remove the hash from URL but I am getting it like (running my application in tomcat)

```
 localhost:8080/resources/list/abc
```

I am expecting something like

```
 localhost:8080/my-app-context/resources/list/abc
```

I have added base tag in my index.html too like the following ways

```
  <base href="/" />
  <base href="my-context-path" />
```

but neither worked.

Moreover after enabling html5 mode, i lost relative lookup for files in the templateUrl

Here is my code

```
 resourcesModule.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

   $urlRouterProvider.when('/resources', '/resources/listView/kristin');
   $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/resources/list/abc');
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/resources/list/abc');

   $stateProvider.state('apptemplates', {
        url: '/apptemplates',
        templateUrl: 'templates/templates.html',
        controller: 'TemplatesNavigationController'
    })
    .state('home', {
        templateUrl: 'my-context-path/home/home.html',
        controller: 'ResourceManagerController'
    })
   .state('home.resources', {
       url: '/resources',
       templateUrl: 'my-context-path/resources/resources.html',
       controller: 'ResourcesController'
   })
   .state('home.resources.listview', {
       url: '/listView/{roleID}',
       templateUrl: 'resourcemanager-ui/resources/listview/listview.html',
       controller: 'ListViewController'
   });

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

One more queston.  Earlier when html5 mode wasn't enabled, it was mapped to

```
 $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/resources/listView/kristin');
```

but after enablng html5 mode it was always routing to 'Otherwise".  Any specific reason.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad, after adding the base tag as follows, things are working fine

```
 <base href="/my-context-path/" />
```

Even relative lookup is working fine